# Eclipse error when trying to import org.apache

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write a program in eclipse that connects to the Twitter's public_timeline.xml,even though i know that link is not available anymore I have some issues when I want to import  the org.apache.commons.*  package.

Any ideea why?Or what I can do to avoid this?

```
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
```

Also I downloaded

1. Jakarta Commons
2. Jakarta Commons Logging
3. Jakarta Commons Codec

and put them in my project

Comment: Please be more specific....

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Get Method can not be resolved.I tried importing some external jar files that correspond

Comment: Can you report here what's the error that you receive?

Comment: When you say 'put them in my project' did you actually add the jars to the project build path?

Comment: Yes,I added them to the project's build path

Answer (score 3):

You need the old apache commons, not jakarta commons:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you just want to download it instead of using Maven (which I do recommend using):
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/commons-httpclient/jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar

In the new one the package structure is different.

(new one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

)

Download link for the new one: http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Comment: where can i download them?

Comment: I've updated my answer with links for both. I do recommend taking a look at maven\ant\... for your dependency management. It will save a lot of headaches. (and most tutorials will mention which dependencies you need)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Maven causes more headaches than it saves.

Comment: @Davio you're going to have to elaborate on that one. For single person projects I can understand your point, and even then I prefer to use a pom since I like to use profiles and a build server), but when working on a team I really don't want to check out\commit jar files.

Comment: Nah, let's not make a huge discussion out of it. I just find that Maven is a poor implementation of a perfectly valid idea. :)

Comment: @Davio I can get not finding maven perfect, it does have its issues. But even then it beats just using your lib folder (which is a joy when you want to transition to webapps). It was more of a recommendation in general to take a look at a dependency management system.

Answer (score -1):

I am using **commons-httpclient-3.1** library and it's working fine with me , download it from here and give it a try: 
http://findjar.com/jar/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar.html

Comment: The developers of the project no longer support this version.  A new, supported version exists, and that's what new projects should use.